# How set photos to an img src from Flickr api in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flickr

I am trying to create a table full of images I get from flickr. The array I pass in contains urls such as:

```
["https://www.flickr.com/photos/113081696@N07/24695273486", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/113081696@N07/24565358002", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/113081696@N07/24033705054", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/30607051@N00/23928266355", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/30735982@N00/23241595406", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/57453294@N00/21232117675", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/57453294@N00/21197130905"]
```

When I try to set the src on an img tag equal to one of these values:

```
var photo = document.createElement("img");
photo.src = arr[i];
```

I just get a bunch of broken picture icons. Can I not use flickr in this way?

Comment: Those are links to photo pages (web page with photo, etc). Just paste one into your browser and see. Are you using the Flickr API?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using the Flickr API.  I created the links using the owner and id from the photos from a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `src` of an img tag should be an url of an image, but

`https://www.flickr.com/photos/113081696@N07/24695273486` is a HTML document

you can use the share button on that page to get piece of HTML code you can embed in your site, see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/s4odszqL/

**UPDATE:**

if you're using flickr api, you can use [getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) to get `farm, server, id, secret` of a photo, then create photo url by following formats [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

Answer (score 2):

Got it!  I have to use flickr's static site by using something like the following:

```
"https://farm" + key.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + key.server + "/" + key.id + "_" + key.secret + ".jpg";
```